# iOS- video streaming from DB is very slow. How can I make it load faster?

Tags: ios, video, video-streaming, avplayer

I'm trying to play a video from a server using Swift.

I have imported AVKit and AVFoundation framework, here is my code:

```
import UIKit
import AVKit
import AVFoundation


class SongViewController: UIViewController, SendInfoDelegate {

let keyPathLoadedTimeRanges = "currentItem.loadedTimeRanges"
var songInfo : Dictionary<String, Any>!
var player : AVPlayer!
var previousVC : UIViewController!
let movie = AVPlayerViewController()
```

.....

```
override func viewWillDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
    player.pause()
    movie.player = nil
    movie.removeFromParentViewController()
    self.removeFromParentViewController()
}

override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    view.addGestureRecognizer(self.revealViewController().panGestureRecognizer())
}
```

....

```
 func loadVideo (videoURL: String) {

    //Load video in Avplayer
    let movieurl : URL = URL(string: videoURL)!

    movie.view.frame = videoContainerView.bounds

    player = AVPlayer(url: movieurl)
    movie.player = player
    self.addChildViewController(movie)
    videoContainerView.addSubview(movie.view)

    player.play()

    player.addObserver(self, forKeyPath: keyPathLoadedTimeRanges, options: .new, context: nil)

    controllsContainerView.frame = videoContainerView.frame
    videoContainerView.addSubview(controllsContainerView)
    controllsContainerView.addSubview(activityIndicatorView)
    activityIndicatorView.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: videoContainerView.centerXAnchor).isActive = true
    activityIndicatorView.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: videoContainerView.centerYAnchor).isActive = true

}
```

for now it takes the video 8-15 seconds to start playing. I must improove the loading time.
On the web site the video begins playing after 3 seconds top's.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out that the video file i'm trying to play is very large due to high frame rate when rendering. (more then 200 MB per video clip)

I re-rendered the video to a 30 frame rate and it made the file much smaller and improved the loading speed dramatically